# on Tomcat run the Index page not reflected

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Does any one tell me that,
when eclipse run how to load index.jsp on server ,
when i run server the index.jsp should be reflect but it not reflecting

Answer (score 0):

You do this using the web.xml file which is stored in the WEB-INF folder

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
  <description>
hello
  </description>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 </web-app>
```

Here the welcome-file is the file you want to load on the server startup..

Hope this helps